# How to summorise 2 form to a 1 form

Tags: php, laravel, forms

I want both `($gateways as $gateway)` and `($local_gateways as $local)` forms to be one form. It should also load `{{route('instantPreview')}}` when clicked on `{{$gateway->name}}` and `{{route('userPaymentPreview')}}` when clicked on `{{$local->name}}`.

```
<div class="card-content">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-pills-icons nav-pills-primary nav-stacked" role="tablist">

                <li class="active">
                    <a href="#instant" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
                        Instant Deposit
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#local" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
                        Local Deposit
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <div class="tab-content">
                <div class="tab-pane active" id="instant">

                    <form action="{{route('instantPreview')}}" method="post">
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                                <div class="form-group label-floating">
                                    <select class="selectpicker" name="gateway" data-style="btn btn-warning btn-round" title="Select Deposit Gateway" data-size="7">

                                        @foreach($gateways as $gateway)
                                            <option value="{{$gateway->id}}">{{$gateway->name}}</option>
                                        @endforeach

                                    </select>

                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>

                        <div class="row">

                            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">

                                <div class="form-group label-floating">

                                    <label  class="control-label" for="amount">Deposit Amount</label>
                                    <input id="amount" name="amount" type="text" class="form-control">

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success pull-right">Deposit Now</button>
                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                    </form>


                </div>
                <br><br>
                <div class="tab-pane" id="local">

                    <form action="{{route('userPaymentPreview')}}" method="post">

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                                <div class="form-group label-floating">
                                    <select class="selectpicker" name="gateway" data-style="btn btn-warning btn-round" title="Select Deposit Gateway" data-size="7">

                                        @foreach($local_gateways as $local)
                                            <option value="{{$local->id}}">{{$local->name}}</option>
                                        @endforeach
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <br>
                        <div class="row">

                            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">

                                <div class="form-group label-floating">

                                    <label  class="control-label" for="amount">Deposit Amount</label>
                                    <input id="amount" name="amount" type="text" class="form-control">

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success pull-right">Deposit Now</button>
                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                    </form>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: wrap them inside the same form(?)

Comment: i tried but then it will redirect to a same form action

Comment: so you want that if the user press the first button the two forms are submitted to a route, and if the user press the second button the two forms are submitted to anothe route?

Comment: i want it to direct to ``{{route('instantPreview')}}`` when select ``<option value="{{$gateway->id}}">{{$gateway->name}}</option>`` ```{{route('userPaymentPreview')}}``` when select ``<option value="{{$local->id}}">{{$local->name}}</option>`` on form

Comment: learn JavaScript, this is a easy script to do with it

Comment: i tried but it wasn't succesful?

Comment: create only one form, first button on click set form action to src1 and then submit, second button on click change form action to src2 and then submit, but if the same data is sent, why just don't use just one controller method

Comment: No, Not the button. I want to direct the option. Example:
Option1 To Url1
Option2 To Url2
How can i do it?